# InstallShield 2013 merge modules - what are they and how do they work?

Tags: merge-module, installshield-2013

We have a product that's been build using InstallShield 2013 that a client is trying to install on a machine without internet connectivity and it's being tripped up trying to download a Microsoft C++ module.

[image]

When I open InstallShield and look at the MSI project and click on the Application Data->Redistributables and search for 2005 I see the picture below which shows that that package is selected for install and it's location is Installed Locally, so shouldn't it be included in our MSI? If I right-click on the package in InstallShield and choose Browse for Merge Module however the resulting folder is empty (of merge modules anyway - there are .dlls there).

[image]

So my question is how would I create a merge module to begin with (given a .dll) and then how do I get it installed into my MSI so that the client doesn't have to download it?

Answer (score 0):

Installed Locally means that your development machine has the bits and thus *can* include it in your built package.

But for it to actually do so, a prerequisite must be configured to do so in one of two ways. Configure it either by right clicking on the item in the Redistributables view to edit its [Properties](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield23helplib/installshield23helplib.htm#helplibrary/IDlgPrereqPropSettings.htm) and change its **Build Location**, or by changing the location of all redistributables in the [Releases view > Setup.exe tab](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield23helplib/installshield23helplib.htm#helplibrary/ReleaseGridSetupTab.htm) > **InstallShield Prerequisites Location**.